# How to load up documentation with Sphinx on a subfolder of Debian server

Tags: nginx, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

I'm quite new to Sphinx side. I have read some stuff about it on Sphinx official documentation site and I have follow these steps for install and configure it on my Debian Wheezy server:

1. First of all I have installed the Sphinx source on http://example.com/documentation-path/.

   > pip install sphinx
2. I have executed the script `sphinx-quickstart` for configuring the root directory and the conf.py.

   > sphinx-quickstart
3. I have executed the `make html` command for building HTML files in my directory path.

   > make html
4. I have installed the Sphinx autobuild for handle every
   changes/updates of my documentation, as written in a [post](http://blog.toast38coza.me/documenting-your-project-with-sphinx/) made by     @[toast38coza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243806/toast38coza).

   > pip install sphinx-autobuild

   > sphinx-autobuild source build/html

[**What I have already fixed**]

My first problem was that I couldn't get a correct view of the documentation index template since the server started watching changes on the documentation files at http://127.0.0.1:8000 (localhost at port 8000). So I get the same url path that I was expecting when I have installed it locally on my current PC. And as I said in the local version test it worked fine.

Since I was searching for something like that as URL path configuration (http://example.com), I decided to add arguments as -host and -port for let it works fine on Debian:

> -p/--port option to specify the port on which the documentation shall be served (default 8000)
> -H/--host option to specify the host on which the documentation shall be served (default 127.0.0.1)

Then I have configured it, launched it and it worked fine:

```
>> sphinx-autobuild source build/html --host http://example.com --port8000
```

So now if I surf http://example.com:8000
I get the correct view of the documentation index template.

**[My main question]**

How can I launch this view on a different URL path, for example a subfolder like http://example.com/documentation-path/, even considering that the root path of the Sphinx installation was /documentation-path/?

**[My secondary question]**

How can I automate the process of visualizing the template view without writing every times the instruction `sphinx-autobuild` with --port and --host on Debian console?

**[Important Notice]**

The Debian server is configured at this moment with NGINX which is completely new for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have solved the subfolder path problem by myself with the help of [NGINX documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/).

```
location /documentation {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

Regarding the autoload problem I have just switched from **Sphinx** to **Markdown** and after that I have used [couscousPHP](https://github.com/CouscousPHP/Couscous) for generate a GitHub pages website from the markdown documentation.

This was for me the smarter way for provide static html files without autoload every time a source from the ssh console. In fact I can easily generate my conversion html file from .md file typing the command `couscous generate`.

Comment: FWIW Sphinx just spits out static HTML files too. `make html` should get you that just fine.